# LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have files where the column is delimited by char(30) and the lines are delimited by char(31). I'm using these delimiters mainly because the columns may contain newline (\n), so the default line delimiter for hive is not useful for us.

I have tried to change the line delimiter in hive but get the error below:

LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now.

Any suggestion?

Write custom SerDe may work?
is there any plan to enhance this functionality in hive in new releases?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, or is the best answer, but when faced with this issue, what we ended up doing is setting the 'textinputformat.record.delimiter' Map/Reduce java property to the value being used.  In our case it was a string "{EOL}", but could be any unique string for all practical purposes.

We set this in our beeline shell which allowed us to pull back the fields correctly.  It should be noted that once we did this, we converted the data to Avro as fast as possible so we didn't need to explain to every user, and the user's baby brother, to set the {EOL} line delimiter.

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter={EOL};
```

Here is the full example.

```
#example CSV data (fields broken by '^' and end of lines broken by the String '{EOL}'

ID^TEXT
11111^Some THings WIth 
New Lines in THem{EOL}11112^Some Other THings..,?{EOL}
111113^Some crazy thin
gs

just crazy{EOL}11114^And Some Normal THings.

#here is the CSV table we laid on top of the data
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE CRAZY_DATA_CSV
(
ID STRING,
TEXT STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\136'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/archive/CRAZY_DATA_CSV'
TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1');

#here is the Avro table which we'll migrate into below.
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE CRAZY_DATA_AVRO
(
ID STRING,
TEXT STRING
)
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION '/archive/CRAZY_DATA_AVRO'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://nameservice/archive/avro_schemas/CRAZY_DATA.avsc');

#And finally, the magic is here.  We set the custom delimiter and import into our Avro table.
set textinputformat.record.delimiter={EOL};
INSERT INTO TABLE CRAZY_DATA_AVRO SELECT * from CRAZY_DATA_CSV;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out by using the option during the extract --hive-delims-replacement ' ' in sqoop so the characters \n \001 \r are removed from the columns.