# XPath expression not working in Hive

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

I have the following XML that I am looking to insert into a Hive table, it's uploaded to HDFS in its own file.

```
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
<Batch>
<Information RptID="23520135" BizDt="2015-01-20"></Information>
<Information RptID="23520378" BizDt="2015-01-20"></Information>
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

Here is my Hive create tables

```
Create TABLE mydata(xmldata string) 
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/john/mydata/';
Drop table mydataview;
CREATE table mydataview(RptID String, BizDt String);
insert overwrite table mydataview select xpath(xmldata ,'//@RptID'),xpath(xmldata ,'//@BizDt') from mydata;
```

The last line (insert overwrite) will fail using the above XML sample above. I believe this is because when I create the table mydata, each line of the XML is getting inserted into the table as a unique row. Therefore, when XPath tries to query the row `<FIXML>` - it blows up. When I strip out the `<Information>` and `<Batch>` elements - the table works as expected.

Is there any way I can insert the entire piece of XML into my table in one row? Or is there another alternative I could do? I'd rather not have to parse out the troublesome elements from the file, but as a last resort I will have to.

Comment: "fails" or "blows up" aren't very explicit. Do you have an exception? A stack trace? Or do the queries simply not return any elements?

Comment: The other notable thing here is that there's a default namespace in play.

Comment: @helb, by the way, `//*[@RptId]` would be the idiom if one were wanting to query the element holding the attribute rather than the attribute itself.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the XPath query itself, or the data. I have verified my XML is valid and my Xpath query itself is good. The problem is more a Hive one - each line is getting treated as its own XML file and when I look for an attribute on the first 2 lines - my Xpath expression naturally fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the idea of setting lines to be terminated by the \003 (EOF char) on my create table, so that the entire file would get read into the single row. Unfortunately this isn't supported by Hive - [LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583736/lines-terminated-by-only-supports-newline-n-right-now)

Looks like the best alternative right now is to pre-process the file.